# How to "effectively" set default error messages of sfValidatorInteger etc.?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I just rumbled into a problem that I assume to be some kind of 'bug' of the symfony framework: I want to set default error messages for different types of validators (e.g. `sfValidatorInteger`). For this, inside of my `ProjectConfiguration::setup` method, I have:

```
sfValidatorBase::setDefaultMessage('required', 'Erforderlich.');
sfValidatorBase::setDefaultMessage('invalid', 'Format ungültig.');
sfValidatorInteger::setDefaultMessage('invalid', '"%value%" ist keine Ganzzahl.');
```

This works fine for `sfValidatorBase` but not for, for example, `sfValidatorInteger`. `sfValidatorInteger` still shows the preset default message `'"%value% is not an integer.'`.

So, I had a look at the implementation of `sfValidatorInteger::configure` and figured out that it sets the instance's error messages hard-coded:

```
protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
{
  $this->addMessage('max', '"%value%" must be at most %max%.');
  $this->addMessage('min', '"%value%" must be at least %min%.');

  $this->addOption('min');
  $this->addOption('max');

  $this->setMessage('invalid', '"%value%" is not an integer.');
}
```

I'd have expected that the error messages are read from the default message map but, obviously, they are not.

So, how could I solve this problem in a clean way preferably without touching the original symfony code (as my changes could be overwritten during future updates)? Should I derive all the validator classes to provide an appropriate `configure` implementation? Well, I don't think so. Setting the error messages for each validator instance separately would also be no (clean) option.

Maybe I got something wrong concerning the configuration of them validators. Then, a more general question would be: How to set default error messages for different validator classes like `'invalid' => '"%value%" ist keine Ganzzahl.'` for `sfValidatorInteger`?

Thanks in advance,
Flinsch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create my own validators extending the default Symfony ones and use those.

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed what I did now. As I use only a few different validators, the effort has paid off. Further advantage: I can generally configure them "in-class" rather than "instance-wise" with my favourite settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this using an xliff translation file.

```
<source>"%value%" is not an integer.</source>
<target>"%value%" n'est pas un entier.</target>
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. Where do I have to place this concrete xliff file? As I understand, the xliff translations require the usage of `__("String to be translated")` to work. But there is no `__()` inside of `sfValidatorInteger`.

Comment: I've seen some calls to translate in sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter, called on the errors, so I guess it should work anyway. You should place this file in the i18n folder of your application. (`apps/yourApp/i18n`)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to implement this. Those application specific xliff files seem only to work for my own uses of `__()`, not for those from other libraries. Furthermore, I would have to create several xliff files, one for every single application. That's not a "clean" way in my opinion. But I thank you. Your advice has been helpful anyway.